# What is regex formula to match two group of words in a body of text

Tags: regex

Please show me the formula to match "alpha" OR "beta" if "delta" OR "gamma" is included in the body of text.

Text example:

***James is alpha but not gamma but he may also be delta***

This should be a match because "alpha" is in the text as well as "gamma".

And I would like it also to have matched because "alpha" is in the text as well as "delta".

The match formula should also apply if "alpha" was replaced by "beta" in the text example.

Comment: What language/tool are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to match the pairs in either order, you can use [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?=.*\b(?:alpha|beta)\b)(?=.*\b(?:gamma|delta)\b).*
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Mbox7i/2).

**Explanation:**

Each lookahead checks that one of the two terms is present somewhere in the string. Both lookaheads need to succeed in order for the match to proceed. The `.*` at the end is not strictly necessary (just to visualize the match in the regex tester); if you only need to check for match/non-match, then you can remove it. In that case, the match result will be an empty string.

Comment: Thank you.  How do I make it work if alpha is after delta?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your regex flavour, this works for you:

```
^                   # beginning of line
    (?=             # start lookahead, zero-lengh assertion that make sure we have within a line
        .*          # 0 or more any character but newline
        \b          # word boundary
        (?:         # start non capture group
            delta   # literally "delta"
          |         # OR
            gamma   # literally "gamma"
        )           # end group
        \b          # word boundary
    )               # end lookahead
    .*              # 0 or more any character but newline
    \b              # word boundary
    (               # start group 1
        alpha       # literally "alpha"
      |             # OR
        beta        # literally "beta"
    )               # end group
    \b              # word boundary
    .*              # 0 or more any character but newline
$                   # end of line
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/RSfAFJ/1)

Comment: Thank you. Much appreciated. Btw, will this work if delta is before alpha in the text

Comment: @ike: Yes it will. But lookahead may not work depending on your regex flavor. What language/tool are you using? PHP, Javascript, editor ...

Comment: I believe it's PHP. It's for an rss feed.  Also, can you tell me how to make the regex case insensitive?

Comment: @ike: Add `(?i)` at the beginning of the regex

Comment: Ok. So will the lookahead work for php? And in this case, is  lookahead the same as lookaround?

Comment: I just tried it. It doesn't work. I could make do with the formula you posted but I would be grateful if you could post a formula that could resolve it. If not, I will make this answer as accepted. Thanks

Comment: Just tried it again. You are right, it does work. Many thanks.